# Tikz Node Text with different size Vertical alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment

I want to align three text to one line, how can I set that?
Thanks a lot

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [right,scale=.5]at (2,6.75) {Example};
\node [right,scale=1]at (2,6.5) {Example};
\node [right,scale=2]at (2,6) {Example};  

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the node is surrounded by an inner and an outer separation frame. You have to set the width of these two to zero with the options `inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt`. You can do it for all nodes in your picture in one place, but usually one wants to modify only a few nodes.

```
\documentclass[border=1]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [right,scale=.5,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]at (2,6.75) {Example};
   \node [right,scale=1,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]at (2,6.5) {Example};
   \node [right,scale=2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]at (2,6) {Example};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now any difference in the indentation is due to the characteristics of the letters, as can be checked by putting the text into a box, `\fbox{Example}`: the left borders form a straight line.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

using option `scale` is not right way to increase font size since it increase also `inner sep` (and `outer sep`) of node. For aligning of node text to node left border, you need to set `inner sep=0pt`:

```
\documentclass[ tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style = {inner sep=0pt, right}
                    ]
\node [scale=.5]    at (2,6.75) {Example};
\node [scale=1]     at (2,6.50) {Example};
\node [scale=2]     at (2,6.00) {Example};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

For comparison see the following example:

```
\documentclass[ tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style = {right}
                    ]
\node [font=\tiny]  at (2,6.75) {Example};
\node []            at (2,6.50) {Example};
\node [font=\huge]  at (2,6.00) {Example};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Edit:**
even more accurate aligning of all of left side of text outer sep to zero: `outer sep=0pt`.

However, your question is not very clear: in title you ask for vertical alignment, but in image you show problem with horizontal ...

Comment: You must also set the `outer sep` to zero.

Comment: probably (difference is negligible) , but the point is my second part of answer ...

Comment: Not probably, but definitely. In another setting `outer sep` may be bigger, and then the answer does not work. The second part of the answer is certainly another option, but it surely looks different. Aesthetically I'd prefer the first version.

Comment: Well, I will not argue with you: (i) all answer indicate (more or less accurate) that source of OP problem is basic properties of node (`inner` and `outer` separation), (ii) if the acceptable solution is set both separation to zero, depends of final application. For example, try to position those nodes with `below right=of s.south west` where `s` is node name. To my opinion the correct way is to select desired font size (as shown in my answer or by `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont`). What gives more aesthetic result is matter of personal taste ... (where we are differ :-) )

Comment: *I will not argue with you* ... I'm just curious what it looks like if you start arguing ;-)

Comment: @Zarko, yes I am wrong, this is horizontal alignment, I just want these different size text in a vertical line.

Answer (score 2):

Besides setting the `inner sep` to zero, as already suggested in other answers I would "restore" the "old"/default `inner sep` value after scaling.

This has the advantage, that the results will not a bit odd when you want to "connect" the nodes with some lines.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        outer sep=auto,
    ]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{0.5}
        \node [right,scale=\scale,inner sep=0.3333em/\scale]
            (small) at (2,6.75) {Example};
        \node [right,scale=1]
            (normal) at (2,6.5) {Example};
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{2}
        \node [right,scale=\scale,inner sep=0.3333em/\scale]
            (large) at (2,6) {Example};

        \draw [black!25] (small.north west) -- (large.south west);
        \draw [red] (1.5,6.5) edge (small.west)
                            edge (normal.west)
                            edge (large.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Nice solution (both, `inner sep` calculated and `outer sep=auto`). To be consistent, the `normal` node should also explicitly set `inner pos` and not rely on `inner pos` having the right value.

Comment: Thank you. I think you meant `inner sep` instead of `inner pos`, right? Of course one would have to add the `inner sep` also to the `normal` node, if the default value would have been changed. But then I would also define a variable for that value and apply it to all three nodes. (But here I wanted to keep the solution quite simple, so I decided to resign this here.)

Comment: Yes, sure, `inner sep`. Anyway, I learned two useful things, thanks.